# Pyinstaller Tkinter hiddenimports = [sysconfig._get_sysconfigdata_name()] ERROR

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

When I try to convert my .py file into an app using pyinstaller, I get the following output on terminal

```
Rishabhs-MacBook-Pro:desktop rishabhtatia$ pyinstaller --clean --hidden-
import tkinter test.py
697 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
697 INFO: Python: 3.6.4
709 INFO: Platform: Darwin-17.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
711 INFO: wrote /Users/rishabhtatia/Desktop/test.spec
714 INFO: UPX is not available.
716 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in /Users/rishabhtatia/Library/Application Support/pyinstaller
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 94, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 791, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 737, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 162, in __init__
    raise ValueError("script '%s' not found" % script)
ValueError: script '/Users/rishabhtatia/Desktop/test.py' not found
Rishabhs-MacBook-Pro:desktop rishabhtatia$ pyinstaller --clean --hidden-import tkinter typeMachine.py
314 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
314 INFO: Python: 3.6.4
321 INFO: Platform: Darwin-17.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
323 INFO: wrote /Users/rishabhtatia/Desktop/typeMachine.spec
326 INFO: UPX is not available.
327 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in /Users/rishabhtatia/Library/Application Support/pyinstaller
328 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/Users/rishabhtatia/Desktop', '/Users/rishabhtatia/Desktop']
328 INFO: checking Analysis
328 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
328 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
332 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
334 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
4406 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tkinter'
4576 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
4586 INFO: Caching module hooks...
4590 INFO: Analyzing /Users/rishabhtatia/Desktop/typeMachine.py
4827 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
5525 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
10217 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
10218 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir '/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/fake-modules'
16738 INFO: Loading module hooks...
16738 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
17122 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
17433 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
17628 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
17630 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
17633 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
17877 INFO: checking Tree
17877 INFO: Building Tree because out00-Tree.toc is non existent
17877 INFO: Building Tree out00-Tree.toc
17888 INFO: checking Tree
17888 INFO: Building Tree because out01-Tree.toc is non existent
17889 INFO: Building Tree out01-Tree.toc
17895 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
17973 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.py"...
17979 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
17981 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module PIL.ImageQt
17981 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
17983 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module PIL.ImageQt
17983 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
17985 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
17985 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
17987 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module PIL.ImageQt
17987 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module PIL.ImageQt
17987 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
18020 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pycparser.py"...
18279 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
18847 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.Image.py"...
19267 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.Qt.py"...
19269 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytest.py"...
20348 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
20349 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 94, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 791, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 737, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 213, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 161, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 472, in assemble
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/imphook.py", line 410, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/imphook.py", line 377, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/compat.py", line 744, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 399, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 823, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 682, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/rishabhtatia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-sysconfig.py", line 42, in <module>
    hiddenimports = [sysconfig._get_sysconfigdata_name()]
TypeError: _get_sysconfigdata_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'check_exists'
```

I've tried to use various different commands with pyinstaller and have tried using py2app with no success.

I'm currently using 
python version: 3.6.4
anaconda version: 1.6.9
macOS HighSierra

Any help on how I can successfully convert this python file into an app will be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same problem.  Upon further investigation, it seems to be the problem with Anaconda introducing breaking changes.

> Please get in touch with the anaconda people then. We can not support their distribution any longer if they add incompatible changes.
>
> I had the same issue before, changing the conda environment's python to 3.5.1 removed that error.
>
> I had the same error (with anaconda as well), but only with python version 3.6.4. If I downgrade to 3.6.3, the error disappears.
>
> If you experience this issue, update your conda installation. If this does not help, get in touch with the anaconda people. We can not support their distribution any longer if they add incompatible changes.

See https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3192 for full discussion.